# Using a QWidget in a Qt View

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Problem: I have a simple QStringListModel that I want to display in a view.  However, I want each item in the view to be a custom QWidget that I have created.  I do not understand why this is such a difficult problem!  I have scoured the internet for solutions and, although I find bits and pieces here and there, no good solution fits all my needs.

The basic code for setting up my model/view:

```
QStringList strings;
// add some strings to the model

QStringListModel* model = new QStringListModel(strings);
QListView* view = new QListView;

view->setModel(model);
```

I have tried various attempts at doing this to no avail.

**Attempt #1**

I tried subclassing a new QItemDelegate object.  Inside this object, I overrode the methods for creating an editor.  I followed all the steps for setting up that delegate.  The problem is that when the view is populated with the model, it grabs each item in the model in Qt::DisplayRole when I need it to grab each item in Qt::EditRole.

**Attempt #2**

Another method I tried was to subclass a QListView, and override the setModel method to call setIndexWidget for each item in the model.  My code looks something this:

```
void CustomListView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel* model)
{
    QListView::setModel(model);

    for (int i = 0; i rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(i, 0);

        CustomWidget* widget = new CustomWidget;
        setIndexWidget(index, widget);
    }
}
```

This worked as far as adding my CustomWidget object to each row in the list view.  In order to ensure that the regular model data was not also shown beneath my CustomWidget objects, I also overrode CustomListView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) to do nothing.  Again, this worked.

But my major issue now is that when the list is displayed, although my CustomWidgets are displayed on it properly, the background of the list is a solid white color.  I tried calling setAutoFillBackground(false) on the CustomListView but that did nothing. I want my list view to have a transparent background.

Any feedback on this problem would be *greatly* appreciated.  I have spent a lot of time trying to get this to work!  Thanks!

Comment: So, regarding attempt #2, I fixed the background issue.  Inside my CustomListView constructor, I called viewport()->setAutoFillBackground(false).  I would still love any more feedback on these methods or other ideas that might work for this problem.

Comment: I think you should stick to delegates. Also you should post the source of your setEditorData() and setModelData() functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot cause all the items in my list to be in EditMode and use the QWidget returned by createEditor() in the delegate.  Seems that only one item at a time can be in that mode.

Comment: regarding your first comment on attempt #2, the qt docs for setItemWidget say: `The given widget's autoFillBackground property must be set to true, otherwise the widget's background will be transparent, showing both the model data and the item at the given index.` so you might want to try that instead of what you did which seems to be the reverse. Going with a custom delegate seems more natural. Having to reimplement paint() when you already have a custom widget that does the job is a bit of a pain though. Could somehow "hijack" your widget's paint method and use it in the delegate?

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a problem similar for rendering custom data in a QStandardItemModel. What I did to solve it was to create a custom QStyledItemDelegate.
In the createEditor method, you can test:

```
if( qVariantCanConvert<YourObject>(index.data(Qt::YourRole)) )
```

Then create your editor which is actually the custom widget you want. And set its value with data from your model.
To customize my widget I used stylesheets like CustomWidget.setStylesheet("background: blue");

In the paint method of your delegate if you want the same widget you do exactly like you did with the editor.

```
CustomWidget renderer;
renderer.setText( index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString() );
renderer.resize(option.rect.size());
painter->save();
painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
renderer.render(painter);
painter->restore();
```

You'll have to handle yourself the openPersistentEditor and closePersistentEditor.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to stick to delegates with custom painting.

See the [Star Delegate Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-stardelegate.html) Like this you paint (see below) the way you want and then edit with `createEditor` when you get the focus.

```
void StarDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
     if (qVariantCanConvert<StarRating>(index.data())) {
         StarRating starRating = qVariantValue<StarRating>(index.data());

         if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
             painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());

         starRating.paint(painter, option.rect, option.palette,
                          StarRating::ReadOnly);
     } else {
         QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
     }
 }
```

The catch or the **cheat** is that you can paint your widget without creating an editor instance or having your widget in *edit mode* using `drawControl()`. See the paint code in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363190/qt-qtableview-how-to-have-a-checkbox-only-column)