# adding a checkbox-column to a custom QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a code to represent a pandas dataframe in a table and provides the filtering functionality as shown in the below:

[image]

I would like to insert a check box column before the first column, so that the user can select rows.
The code uses a `PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel)` model to read pandas data and a `CustomProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel)` to add filtering capability for the `QTableView`.

My question is if I need to add the additional checkbox column, should I add it in the`PandasModel` or in the `CustomProxyModel` or somewhere else? As an alternative solution, I found an [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748546/pyqt-column-of-checkboxes-in-a-qtableview) suggesting to use a custom `CheckBoxDelegate` (which I added in the code below) but it seems to occupy the first column instead of inserting a new column. also it does not allow clicking.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd

class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()
        self.bolds = dict()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
                return self.bolds.get(section, QtCore.QVariant())
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    # return self.df.index.tolist()
                    return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setFont(self, section, font):
        self.bolds[section] = font
        self.headerDataChanged.emit(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 0, self.columnCount())

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()


class CustomProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filters = dict()

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

    def setFilter(self, expresion, column):
        if expresion:
            self.filters[column] = expresion
        elif column in self.filters:
            del self.filters[column]
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        for column, expresion in self.filters.items():
            text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent).data()
            regex = QtCore.QRegExp(
                expresion, QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
            )
            if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                return False
        return True

class CheckBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning QCheckBox cell of the column to which it's applied.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        """
        Important, otherwise an editor is created if the user clicks in this cell.
        """
        return None

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        """
        Paint a checkbox without the label.
        """
        self.drawCheck(painter, option, option.rect, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if int(index.data()) == 0 else QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        '''
        Change the data in the model and the state of the checkbox
        if the user presses the left mousebutton and this cell is editable. Otherwise do nothing.
        '''
        if not int(index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable) > 0:
            return False

        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # Change the checkbox-state
            self.setModelData(None, model, index)
            return True

        return False

    def setModelData (self, editor, model, index):
        '''
        The user wanted to change the old state in the opposite.
        '''
        model.setData(index, 1 if int(index.data()) == 0 else 0, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    """
    A simple table to demonstrate the QComboBox delegate.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, CheckBoxDelegate(self))

class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = TableView(self)
        self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")

        self.load_sites()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["{0}".format(col) for col in self.model._df.columns])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)


    def load_sites(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'site_codes': ['01', '02', '03', '04'],
                           'status': ['open', 'open', 'open', 'closed'],
                           'Location': ['east', 'north', 'south', 'east'],
                           'data_quality': ['poor', 'moderate', 'high', 'high']})

        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.proxy = CustomProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

        # delegate = CheckBoxDelegate(None)
        # self.view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):

        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = self.model._df.iloc[:, self.logicalIndex].unique()

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()
        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)
        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter("", filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter(stringAction, filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        self.proxy.setFilter(text, self.proxy.filterKeyColumn())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(2000, 800)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CustomProxyModel is not an option because it does not allow you to correctly map checkboxes since the number and row shown varies. One possible solution is to implement a proxy (maybe based on QAbstractProxyModel or QIdentityProxyModel) implementing that functionality but in my answer I will not propose that solution since it can complicate the logic, instead I will implement the logic in the source model so I have created a class inherited from PandasModel where a column for checkboxes is added.

The logic is override data, setData, flags and headarData methods so that the information in the column greater than the checkbox column is taken from the base class but decreased by 1.

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd


class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()
        self.bolds = dict()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
                return self.bolds.get(section, QtCore.QVariant())
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                try:
                    # return self.df.index.tolist()
                    return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
                except (IndexError,):
                    return QtCore.QVariant()
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setFont(self, section, font):
        self.bolds[section] = font
        self.headerDataChanged.emit(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 0, self.columnCount())

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, "toPyObject"):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == "" else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(
            colname, ascending=order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True
        )
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()


class CheckablePandasModel(PandasModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super().__init__(df, parent)
        self.checkable_values = set()
        self._checkable_column = -1

    @property
    def checkable_column(self):
        return self._checkable_column

    @checkable_column.setter
    def checkable_column(self, column):
        if self.checkable_column == column:
            return
        last_column = self.checkable_column
        self._checkable_column = column

        if last_column == -1:
            self.beginInsertColumns(
                QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.checkable_column, self.checkable_column
            )
            self.endInsertColumns()

        elif self.checkable_column == -1:
            self.beginRemoveColumns(QtCore.QModelIndex(), last_column, last_column)
            self.endRemoveColumns()
        for c in (last_column, column):
            if c > 0:
                self.dataChanged.emit(
                    self.index(0, c), self.index(self.columnCount() - 1, c)
                )

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return super().columnCount(parent) + (1 if self.checkable_column != -1 else 0)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if self.checkable_column != -1:
            row, col = index.row(), index.column()
            if col == self.checkable_column:
                if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
                    return (
                        QtCore.Qt.Checked
                        if row in self.checkable_values
                        else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
                    )
                return QtCore.QVariant()
            if col > self.checkable_column:
                index = index.sibling(index.row(), col - 1)
        return super().data(index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if self.checkable_column != -1:
            row, col = index.row(), index.column()
            if col == self.checkable_column:
                if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
                    if row in self.checkable_values:
                        self.checkable_values.discard(row)
                    else:
                        self.checkable_values.add(row)
                    self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (role,))
                    return True
                return False
            if col > self.checkable_column:
                index = index.sibling(index.row(), col - 1)
        return super().setData(index, value, role)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if self.checkable_column != -1:
            if section == self.checkable_column and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant()
            if section > self.checkable_column and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                section -= 1
        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        if self.checkable_column != -1:
            col = index.column()
            if col == self.checkable_column:
                return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
            if col > self.checkable_column:
                index = index.sibling(index.row(), col - 1)
        return super().flags(index)


class CustomProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filters = dict()

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

    def setFilter(self, expresion, column):
        if expresion:
            self.filters[column] = expresion
        elif column in self.filters:
            del self.filters[column]
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        for column, expresion in self.filters.items():
            text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent).data()
            regex = QtCore.QRegExp(
                expresion, QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
            )
            if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                return False
        return True


class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")

        self.load_sites()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["{0}".format(col) for col in self.model._df.columns])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(
            self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked
        )

    def load_sites(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "site_codes": ["01", "02", "03", "04"],
                "status": ["open", "open", "open", "closed"],
                "Location": ["east", "north", "south", "east"],
                "data_quality": ["poor", "moderate", "high", "high"],
            }
        )

        self.model = CheckablePandasModel(df)
        self.model.checkable_column = 0
        self.proxy = CustomProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        if logicalIndex == self.model.checkable_column:
            return

        self.menuValues = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(
            logicalIndex - 1
            if logicalIndex > self.model.checkable_column
            else logicalIndex
        )
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = set(
            self.proxy.index(i, logicalIndex).data()
            for i in range(self.proxy.rowCount())
        )

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()
        for i, name in enumerate(valuesUnique):
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(name, self)
            action.setData(i)
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)

        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        pos = headerPos + QtCore.QPoint(
            self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(logicalIndex),
            self.horizontalHeader.height(),
        )
        action = self.menuValues.exec_(pos)
        if action is not None:
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            if action.data() is None:  # all
                self.proxy.setFilter("", logicalIndex)
            else:
                font.setBold(True)
                self.proxy.setFilter(action.text(), logicalIndex)
            self.model.setFont(logicalIndex - 1, font)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        self.proxy.setFilter(text, self.comboBox.currentIndex() + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(2000, 800)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great help. There are three issues to be addressed: (1) When you filter a column, the next column gets the bold font (I guess you need change `self.bolds[section]` to `self.bolds[section-1]`)  ; (2) the regex filter does not work, it seems that it is connected to the checkbox column only; and (3) The `AND` operation between columns does not work on the unique list provided, for example in your figure `data_quality` is filtered but if you click on the `Location` column, you will see all unique values. I expect to see all the Locations that have `High` data quality.

Comment: @BehzadJamali I have just seen your comment, I will analyze what you say

Comment: The third problem still exists. to reproduce the problem: click on the last column and filter `data_quality` to `high` values. Now when you click on `location` column, you should only see `south` and `east` but you see all existing unique values instead.

Comment: @BehzadJamali Did your code work that way or is it a new feature that you require? I point it out because `self.model._df.iloc[:, self.logicalIndex].unique()` doesn't do what you point out.

Comment: I'm not sure if it used to work that way before adding the checkbox option

Comment: @BehzadJamali Mmm, don't you think it's strange that you say my code has a problem with something that never worked? For this only time I will add that functionality that you do not indicate anywhere in your question and that was not part of the behavior of your original code, on other occasions you will have to create a new question.

Comment: @BehzadJamali I already added this functionality, please do not do the same, it is uncomfortable to ask for something you never pointed out.