Center a Checkbox Delegate in QTableView with PySide6
I was using a Checkbox Delegate in my QTableView originally created from around the time of PyQt 4.8 or PySide 1.2.1.  It was also working in PySide2, but when I tried to update my application to PySide6, it no longer worked (I now no longer remember exactly what the problem was).
A newer version was posted for PyQt5 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50314085/224310 which mostly worked except that the delegate was a subclass of QItemDelegate instead of QStyledItemDelegate the checkboxes were drawn horribly large.  Others seemed to have the same issue, as I found at https://forum.qt.io/topic/142124/pyqt-checkbox-resolution-for-different-scales, but the poster indicated they ultimately solved their problem "by implementing the checkboxes through Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable, rather than through a delegate".  I tried the same and it worked, but it seems that checkboxes implemented through Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable are not able to be centered in a column of a QTableView.  To center them you need... a delegate.
I've spent hours upon hours researching and trying different solutions and it amazes me that what seems like a common use-case of a column of centered checkboxes in a QTableView is so difficult to implement in Python.  (Ok, I've worked with Qt long enough that I'm not really amazed.)
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement a column of check boxes in PySide6 that are centered in a column and do not look horrible at large resolutions?
(I'll be answering my own question and posting my ultimate solution below, but I'd welcome other (better) suggestions as well!)

Reading posts with someone else's similar struggles, I ran across a link to a C++ solution at https://wiki.qt.io/Center_a_QCheckBox_or_Decoration_in_an_Itemview.  I was not able to find a similar solution written in Python directly.  I don't know C++, but with the help of an online conversion tool, I was able to get version that looked somewhat-like-Python, which I was then able to rewrite to work with PySide6 and with something more modern (I'm using Python 3.12).

from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class StyledCheckboxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    """Centered checkbox delegate to use in a QTableView.

    Adapted from https://wiki.qt.io/Center_a_QCheckBox_or_Decoration_in_an_Itemview
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent=parent)


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        self.initStyleOption(option, index)
        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style() if widget else QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        style.drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_PanelItemViewItem,
                option,
                painter,
                widget
                )

        if (QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.ViewItemFeature.HasCheckIndicator
                in option.features):
            if option.checkState == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
                option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Off

            elif option.checkState == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.PartiallyChecked:
                option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_NoChange

            elif option.checkState == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_On

            rect = style.subElementRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SubElement.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator,
                option,
                widget
                )
            option.rect = QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
                option.direction,
                QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag(
                        index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.TextAlignmentRole).value
                        ),
                rect.size(),
                option.rect
                )
            option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_HasFocus
            style.drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck,
                option,
                painter,
                widget
                )

        elif not option.icon.isNull():
            icon_rect = style.subElementRect(
                    QtWidgets.QStyle.SubElement.SE_ItemViewItemDecoration,
                    option,
                    widget
                    )
            icon_rect = QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
                    option.direction,
                    QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag(
                            index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.TextAlignmentRole).value
                            ),
                    icon_rect.size(),
                    option.rect
                    )
            mode = QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Normal
            if QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Enabled not in option.state:
                mode = QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Disabled

            elif QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected in option.state:
                mode = QtGui.QIcon.Mode.Selected

            state = (
                    QtGui.QIcon.State.On
                    if QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Open in option.state
                    else QtGui.QIcon.State.Off
                    )
            option.icon.paint(
                    painter,
                    icon_rect,
                    option.decorationAlignment,
                    mode,
                    state
                    )

        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)


    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):

        # Make sure that the item is checkable
        flags = model.flags(index)
        if (QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable not in flags
                or QtWidgets.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Enabled not in option.state
                or QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled not in flags):
            return False

        # Make sure that we have a check state
        state = index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        if state is None:
            return False

        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style() if widget else QtWidgets.QApplication.style()

        # Make sure that we have the right event type
        if event.type() in (
                QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease,
                QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonDblClick,
                QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress,
                ):
            view_opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            self.initStyleOption(view_opt, index)
            check_rect = style.subElementRect(
                    QtWidgets.QStyle.SubElement.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator,
                    view_opt,
                    widget,
                    )
            check_rect = QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
                    view_opt.direction,
                    QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag(
                            index.data(QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.TextAlignmentRole).value
                            ),
                    check_rect.size(),
                    view_opt.rect,
                    )
            if (isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent)
                    and (event.button() != QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton
                         or not check_rect.contains(event.position().toPoint())
                         )):
                return False

            if event.type() in (
                    QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress,
                    QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonDblClick,
                    ):
                return True

        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
            if event.key() not in (
                    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Space,
                    QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Select,
                    ):
                return False

        else:
            return False

        # convert to an Enum for easy comparison
        state = QtCore.Qt.CheckState(state)
        if QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserTristate in flags:
            state = QtCore.Qt.CheckState((state.value + 1) % 3)

        else:
            state = (
                    QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked
                    if state == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
                    else QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
                    )

        # set the new checkbox state in the model (as its Enum value)
        return model.setData(
                index,
                state.value,
                QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole,
                )



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    model.setColumnCount(1)
    model.setRowCount(2)

    checkable_item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    checkable_item.setFlags(
            checkable_item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable
            )
    checkable_item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    checkable_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
    model.setItem(0, 0, checkable_item)

    checkable_item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    checkable_item.setFlags(
            checkable_item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable
            )
    checkable_item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    checkable_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked)
    model.setItem(1, 0, checkable_item)

    table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    table_view.setModel(model)
    table_view.setItemDelegate(StyledCheckboxDelegate())
    #table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, StyledCheckboxDelegate()) # when only a single column should use the delegate
    table_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Hopefully this saves someone else (or my future self) some hours of time looking for a similar solution!
